# Lua Box2d Gideros: Hide bodies

Tags: lua, box2d, game-physics, gideros

In Gideros studio box2d, bodies(which are basicly the physical object, not the picture that goes with it) always show up as a translucent shape. In my game, i don't want players to be able to see these bodies. I've seen that you can do this in corona, but I haven't seen anything about Gideros. Is there anyone who knows lua and box2d well enough to tell me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you have physics debug drawing enabled

Comment: Thanks! I was editing an example that I downloaded, and I didn't see that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really debug drawing, then click on top menu Edit, choose Find in files and search for `DebugDraw`

You should find something like:

```
local world = b2.World.new(0, 10, true)
local debugDraw = b2.DebugDraw.new()
world:setDebugDraw(debugDraw)
stage:addChild(debugDraw)
```

Just comment out the line `--stage:addChild(debugDraw)` and you are good to go.
Remove setting debug draw completely for production for better performance

You can setup some global variable debug and toggle it to enable/disable debug drawing:

```
DEBUG = false
```

and then later in your code

```
if DEBUG then
    local world = b2.World.new(0, 10, true)
    local debugDraw = b2.DebugDraw.new()
    world:setDebugDraw(debugDraw)
    stage:addChild(debugDraw)
end
```